# What does the dash star dash (-*-) do in a Ruby file?

Tags: ruby

I've noticed some Ruby files have a section at the very top like the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
```

An example is a Vagrantfile generated by [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

What does that section actually do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [file mode specification](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html) for emacs

> When you visit a file, Emacs chooses a major mode automatically. Normally, it makes the choice based on the file name—for example, files whose names end in ‘.c’ are normally edited in C mode—but sometimes it chooses the major mode based on special text in the file. This special text can also be used to enable buffer-local minor modes.

It basically tells Emacs to use ruby mode